# Qgis crashes upon starting

Tags: installation, qgis

I get the following error output upon trying to open Qgis Desktop. This recently started happening after updating VMWare.

I've tried un-installing and re-installing Qgis already. I ran `sudo apt-get remove qgis` and `sudo apt-get remove python-qgis` as well as `sudo apt-get remove *qgis*`

```
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
Warning: QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/jusnguy/.qgis2//project_templates
Warning: QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QgsPanelWidgetStack "mWidgetStack", which already has a layout
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem on another system.
Did you try to also update Qt before update QGis? It worked for me.

Regards.